# How to stock the value of an object in a for each

Tags: javascript

I am working on an invoice app.

An for each invoice (object), I want to display a status. Here is my function:

```
  displayInvoicesStatus (data) {
data.forEach(invoice => {
  if ( !invoice.validatedAt ) {
    this.invoiceStatus = "En attente de validation"
  }
  else if ( !invoice.sentAt  ) {
    this.invoiceStatus = "En attente d'envoi"
  }
  else if ( !invoice.paidAt  ) {
    this.invoiceStatus = "En attente de paiement"
  }
  else {
    this.invoiceStatus = "Payée"
  }

})
```

}

My problem is the following, it is the last object in my loop that is rendered in my variable "invoiceStatus" for every line. I am not stocking the value for each object and I don't know how to do it.

Can you provide any assistance?

Warm regards
Mathieu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `map` method of array to handle this.

> The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```
function displayInvoicesStatus(data) {
  return data.map(invoice => {
    if (!invoice.validatedAt) {
      invoice.invoiceStatus = "En attente de validation";
    } else if (!invoice.sentAt) {
      invoice.invoiceStatus = "En attente d'envoi";
    } else if (!invoice.paidAt) {
      invoice.invoiceStatus = "En attente de paiement";
    } else {
      invoice.invoiceStatus = "Payée";
    }
    return invoice;
  });
}
```